# Importing SSL Certificate to Java

Tags: java, ssl, keytool

I am trying to invoke an method from a JAR library which calls an web service. When I call the required method, I am getting the below error.

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
```

I have a valid SSL certificate file(ssl_file.pfx) and a password. When I Google, all results were asking to use Keytool to add the certificate to cacert.

when I tried the below command, I am getting "Input not an X.509 certificate" message.

```
keytool -import -file ssl_file.pfx -alias somealias -keystore keystore_file -storepass changeit
```

**NOTE:** I don't have admin access for the JRE /lib/security/cacerts file/folder.

How can I resolve this? Is there any other option to do this via program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PFX files are not certificates (assuming you're using the usual extension correctly), they're PKCS#12 stores, containing both certificates a private keys.

`keytool` can treat such files as `PKCS12` keystores, so you can export your certificate (without its private key) using:

```
keytool -exportcert -file cert.crt -keystore ssl_file.pfx -storetype PKCS12 -alias ...
```

(First use `-list` instead of `-exportcert` if you don't know the existing alias name.)

Then, import that certificate:

keytool -importcert -file cert.crt -alias somealias -keystore keystore_file ...

This being said, unless it's a self-signed certificate, you should generally not do any of this, rather import the CA certificate in your truststore.

Comment: What should I use for alias.. When I use -list it does not show any alias details.

Comment: It will show an alias, that might be `1` for example.

Comment: This is the output of -list after providing the password. Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 0 entries. Out of this, which is the alias, please.

Comment: If you have 0 entries in your `ssl_file.pfx`, there's obviously something wrong with your file: it's empty. Are you sure you haven't overwritten it or something with a previous command attempt?

Comment: Thanks. I got alais now. I am getting error when using exportcert and importcert.. but it works when I use just export and import. Can you confirm?

Comment: Not sure which version of `keytool` you're using. See last paragraph of the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html) "*The command interface for keytool changed in Java SE 6. [...] `-export`, renamed to `-exportcert`*". Anyway, use the one that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Accepted your answer.